# How to skip labels and citations when spellchecking

Tags: spelling

I want to spell-check a rather large article. In this article there are many labels (atleast 50) for theorems, figures etc. which have informal names (usually an acronym of some sort), which trigger the spell-check unnecessarily. I would like to remove this inefficiency, and ignore everything inside \label{},\cite{} etc, what is the simplest solution?

(I usually use texworks or texmaker)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Make all your labels correctly spelled words?  You can put blanks into labels, IIRC.